# How to retrieve date properly using spreadsheet gem in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spreadsheet

The date column in spreadsheet is formatted as `'mm/dd/yyyy'`
But when I read the above column via spreadsheet the format is different than the above format.

My code is as follows:

```
require 'spreadsheet'

Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
book = Spreadsheet.open params[:excel_file]
sheet1 = book.worksheet 0
sheet1.each do |row|
  row.set_format 1, Spreadsheet::Format.new(:number_format => 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  h = Hash.new
  h["name"] = row[0]
  h["date"] = row[1]
  ......
end
```

Currently h["date"] is not retrieving properly. So How should I retrieve the date column properly with my original formatting. Can anyone help me to sort this out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`row[1].date` or `row[1].datetime` will get you the right value.  I suppose you can set the format while writing it to excel not the other way round.

**Update**
I thought you just needed your excel date translated as ruby date.
This should do the trick:
`excel_date = row[1].date`
`ruby_date = excel_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`