# Ruby spreadsheet datetime error

Tags: ruby, regex, spreadsheet

I have a row that looks like the following (in a .xls):

```
bob    abc    6/14/14 8:23
```

I want to return the date and time as: 61414823

I tried to get started with:

```
def self.regex_date
_test_column = @sheet.row(1)[2].date
...
end
```

Which I read about here: [How to retrieve date properly using spreadsheet gem in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879118/how-to-retrieve-date-properly-using-spreadsheet-gem-in-ruby)

But I'm getting the following error, before I can get to the regex part:

```
in `regex_date': undefined method `date' for #<DateTime:0x007f94e111b700> (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `@sheet.row(1)[2]` is a [`DateTime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) object. It doesn't have `.date` method. Instead, you can use [`.to_date`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-to_date).

But I don't understand why do you want to convert it to `Date`. What you want is to use [`.strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime) like this:

```
@sheet.row(1)[2].strftime("%-m%-d%y%-k%M")
DateTime.new(2014, 6, 14, 8, 23).strftime("%-m%-d%y%-k%M") # => "61414823"
```